# Angular directive unit test issue when passing data into the directive for testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

Angular directive unit test issue when passing data into the directive for testing.

I'm having trouble when I pass a data object into the directive.

I get the following error: "**Syntax Error: Token 'Object' is unexpected, expecting []] at column 9 of the expression [[object Object]] starting at [Object]]**"

**This is my unit test:**

```
describe("Pagination:", function () {

    var element,
      scope,
      mockData,
      rootScope;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("myApp"));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        //Seems to be an issue here:
        mockData = {
            data: [],
            meta: {},
            links: {}
        };

        element = "<pagination data=\"" + mockData + "\"></pagination>"; 
        element = $compile(element)(scope);

        angular.element(document.body).append(element);

        scope.$digest();
    }));           

    it("should emit for more data when get data is called", function () {
        sinon.stub(scope, "$emit");
        scope.getData("dummyUrl");

        expect(scope.$emit.calledWith("pagination:getTabPage", "dummyUrl")).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

**The test seems fine.
Just seems to be an issue with the setup of the test.**

**This is the html:**

```
 <pagination data="data"></pagination>
```

**This is the directive I'm looking to test:**

```
angular.module("myApp")
    .directive("pagination", [function() {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                data: "="
            },
            templateUrl: "pagination.html",
            link: function(scope) {
                scope.totalPages = scope.data.meta["total-pages"];

                scope.getData = function(pageUrl) {
                    if (pageUrl !== null) {
                        scope.$emit("pagination:getTabPage", pageUrl);
                    }
                };
            }
        };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for `mockData` needs to be encoded prior to being joined into a string.

```
element = "<pagination data=\"" + angular.toJson(mockData) + "\"></pagination>";
```

The other option would be to simply add the `mockData` object as a property on the `scope` and reference that in the HTML that you are compiling in your test.

```
scope.mockData = { … };
element = "<pagination data='mockData'></pagination>";
element = $compile(element)(scope);
```

**This is my beforeEach:**

```
 beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        scope.mockData = {
            data: [],
            meta: {},
            links: {}
        };

        element = "<pagination data='mockData'></pagination>";
        element = $compile(element)(scope);

        angular.element(document.body).append(element);

        scope.$digest();

         otherScope = element.isolateScope();
    }));
```

Comment: I tried that and got a new error: " Unexpected end of expression: { "

Comment: Looking over it again, you could also add the `mockData` object as a property on `scope`, and then just reference that in the html.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you add your example

Comment: I've added my attempt above with your changes but It still doesnt work. This is the error I get: "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'scope.getData("dummyUrl")')
"

Comment: I got it working. I needed to add otherScope = element.isolateScope(); I will update your answer